# NearProtocol simulation test example not compiling

Tags: nearprotocol

TLDR: NEAR's FungibleToken example is the goto standard for how to write simulation tests, and it isn't compiling.

https://github.com/thor314/FungibleToken
details my odyssey of trying to get the Fungible Token example to compile, so I can model my Simulation Tests off of it. The ReadMe contains what I've tried so far.

The original repo lives inside the `near_sdk` repo.
https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/tree/master/examples/fungible-token

---

After @sirwillem's useful answer, this post is updated to reflect a residing error in the sim test:

```
---- test_sim_transfer stdout ----
thread 'test_sim_transfer' panicked at 'Outcome ExecutionOutcome {
    logs: [],
    receipt_ids: [
        `9S5QHJgLThMCPtgJbtARenx6duSLBu3oCCtVbVpEwdLC`,
    ],
    burnt_gas: 16326564288269,
    tokens_burnt: 0,
    status: Failure(Action #0: The account contract wouldn't have enough balance to cover storage, required to have 116059483300000000000000000 yoctoNEAR more),
} was a failure', /home/thor/.cargo/git/checkouts/near-sdk-rs-7ba52202f378a9d9/ea112e2/near-sdk-sim/src/outcome.rs:87:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

---

Update 2; needed to update the .wasm file with the build script. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for trudging into uncharted territory!  We are still working to publish core crates in nearcore that the simulator depends on.  Once we have this, we can publish it.  This will stabilize it and you won't get these types of errors.

For now to fix what you have edit your Cargo.toml to the newest tag for both:

```
[dependencies]
near-sdk = { git = "https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs.git", tag="2.2.0" }


[dev-dependencies]
near-sdk-sim = { git = "https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs.git", tag="2.2.0" }
```

Then you have to edit `general.rs` on line 70 to:

```rust
        contract.transfer(alice.account_id(), transfer_amount.into()),
```

Comment: Thanks @sirwillem! After a quick clearup on a test on lib.rs line 347 to change the expected message on default (I changed the message, oops), I'm getting another error, shown above in the post.